# How to delete all text after and including delimiter in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do the following with a text document that I have:

1. Import .txt file using ruby, split it by line, and push it to an array
2. Remove all characters after and including a specific delimiter for all strings in the array
3. Write each array element back to a new line in a new text file.

I'm trying to do this using ruby and I've got step one working, but I can't get past step two. I'm stuck right now with an array of strings. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to remove all characters after what?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to get you started on doing what you want. You may want to make it more compact but I made it verbose so you could follow the flow

```
path_to_file = '/dir_path_to_file'
delimiter = ':'

strings = %w(aa:aa bb:bb cc:cc dd:dd) # this is some test data. replace with your array read in from file

# Open file for writing
File.open(path_to_file, 'w') do |file|
  strings.each do |string|

    index_of_delimiter = string.index(delimiter)

    stripped_string = string.slice(0..index_of_delimiter - 1)

    # append line to file with \n for new line
    file << stripped_string << "\n"

   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a text file like this:

```
aaa
bbb
BEGIN
xxx
xxx
END
ccc
```

There is a "dirty" little Ruby trick you can use with the flip-flop operator:

```
# Load file
lines = File.readlines("the_text_file")

# Reject all lines between BEGIN and END
lines.reject! { |line| true if (line =~ /^BEGIN/)..(line =~ /^END/) }

# Output result
puts lines
```

Output:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Comment: They're looking to chop each line: "split it by line, and push it to an array 2) Remove all characters after and including a specific delimiter for all strings in the array"

Comment: @mu - Riiight..oops..ok. Well they better describe their questions better next time so I don't provide useless answers :) It's still a neat trick though. I leave it here free of charge.

Comment: It's called a flip-flop operator, not a range operator.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to read entire file upfront. Just process line by line. There is even a ruby's command-line switch for it (`-n`).

Say your delimiter is `|`:

```
cat inputfile | ruby -ne 'puts $_.sub /\|.*/, ""' > outputfile
```

or (using `-p` switch),

```
cat inputfile | ruby -pe '$_.sub! /\|.*/, ""' > outputfile
```